# Finding specific tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here is the website that i'm parsing: http://uniapple.net/usaddress/address.php?address1=501+10th+ave&address2=&city=nyc&state=ny&zipcode=10036&country=US

I would like to be able to find the word that will be in line 39 between the td tags. That line tells me if the address is residential or commercial, which is what I need for my script.

Here's what I have, but i'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'
```

The code I'm using is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib


page = "http://uniapple.net/usaddress/address.php?address1=501+10th+ave&address2=&city=nyc&state=ny&zipcode=10036&country=US"
z = urllib.urlopen(page).read()
thesoup = BeautifulSoup(z, "html.parser")
comres = (thesoup.find("th",text=" Residential or ").find_next("td").text)
print(str(comres))
```

Comment: That just means that the soup.find("th", text = "Residential or ") doesn't return anything

Comment: Does the order of the headers change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` argument would not work in this particular case. This is related to how the [`.string` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) of an element is calculated. Instead, I would use a [search function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) where you can actually call `get_text()` and check the complete "text" of an element including the children nodes:

```
label = thesoup.find(lambda tag: tag and tag.name == "th" and \
                                 "Residential" in tag.get_text())
comres = label.find_next("td").get_text()
print(str(comres))
```

Prints `Commercial`.

We can go a little bit further and make a *reusable function* to get a value by label:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(z, "html.parser")

def get_value_by_label(soup, label):
    label = soup.find(lambda tag: tag and tag.name == "th" and label in tag.get_text())
    return label.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)


print(get_value_by_label(soup, "Residential"))
print(get_value_by_label(soup, "City"))
```

Prints:

```
Commercial
NYC
```

Answer (score 1):

All you are missing is a bit of housekeeping:

```
ths = thesoup.find_all("th")
for th in ths:
    if 'Residential or' in th.text:
        comres = th.find_next("td").text
        print(str(comres))
        >> Commercial
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use a regular expression as your text field, like `re.compile('Residential or')`, rather than a string.

This was working for me. I had to iterate over the results provided, though if you only expect a single result per page you could swap `find` for `find_all`:

```
for r in thesoup.find_all(text=re.compile('Residential or')):
    r.find_next('td').text
```